# css Flex обрезание верха при большом внутреннем элементе

Tags: css, flexbox

сразу пример:
html =>

```
<div class="box">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

css =>

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

=>

```
.box div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

то есть отцентрировали внутренний блок и при его росте будет прокрутка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь меняем высоты блока:

```
.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
 }
```

снизу всё хорошо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну а свехру идёт обрезание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как добиться того, что бы данного обрезания не просходило?

Comment: Живой пример добавляй, а не писалки.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обрезания не происходило, можно родительскому блоку добавить padding-top (или дочернему - margin-top):

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.box div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: blue;
   border-radius: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю другой способ, может кому пригодится, без лишних padding-ов. Просто не указывать у flex контейнера св-в отвечающих за центрирование содержимого, а выравнивать по центу с помощью margin: auto; у дочернего элемента div.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}

.box div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 400px;
   background-color: blue;
   border-radius: 50px;
   margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
   <div></div>
</div>
```